# Multi-OS Engine not compatible with Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra

Tags: ios, android-studio, intellij-idea, libgdx

What are the implications of this message installing Multi-OS Engine from Intel on my Mac OSX Sierra:

> Unsupported OS Detected operating system is not supported. Supported
>   operating systems for this release are:  OS X* 10.9 (Intel(R) 64),
>   10.10 (Intel(R) 64), 10.11 (Intel(R) 64)

Installation succeed and I can debug app from Android Studio Plugin, but I'm having problems Building IPA to Deploy App to AppStore. Is this a common problem from Multi-OS Engine executing on Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra? Are there any other problems and is there guide to solve them?

I'm using LibGDX to develop a game. This is what I see when I go to Build > Export IPA for Application:

[image: Android Studio: Build > Export IPA for Application]

There is no Module Name, iOS SDK and Provisioning Profile available.

Comment: I have the same issue, no Module Name, and also no iOS SDK ... did you manage to get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no MOE installation necessary anymore. Look at [this page](https://multi-os-engine.org/start/) for more information. MOE sdk is available via gradle. And I used it with Sierra